# Parse error. Function missing ending ")" CMAKE

Tags: cmake

I wanted to extract a string from a header in an `execute_process`. 
But there is a bug with the command and I try a lot of things, always the same error.

`execute_process`(
    `COMMAND` cat $(version_h)  | grep -a "define myVersion " | cut -d " " -f3 | cut -d '"' -f2`

OUTPUT_VARIABLE _Version)

If I write the command in the console line, there is no problem.

The error says: "Parse error.  Function missing ending ")".  Instead found unterminated string with text "
"

Comment: Variables in CMake are accessed the following way `${Variable}`. Please note the curly braces.

Comment: You also seem to have an additional backtick after f2 in your post. Is that a copy error or is it part of the command?

Comment: I need to set  " ` " before cat and after f2 but it is for write command in stackoverflow. Example : `command`

Comment: I think it is an escape character matter because if I write '\"', the configuration is done.

Comment: @sovif: Backtricks ("\`") are used for *inline code* formatting, for format *multiline code* use (with code selected) tool button `{}` or `Ctrl+K` keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I need to remove a quote character and I guess there is a confusion with Cmake and the bash command.

`execute_process(COMMAND cat ... COMMAND grep ... COMMAND cut ... COMMAND cut -c2- COMMAND rev COMMAND cut -c2- COMMAND rev OUTPUT_VARIABLE _Version)`

Answer (score 0):

`execute_process()` only deals with processes and their arguments, i.e. there is no shell involved.

So, you have two main options:

1. `execute_process(COMMAND bash -c "..." OUTPUT_VARIABLE _Version)`
2. `execute_process(COMMAND cat ... COMMAND grep ... COMMAND cut ... COMMAND cut ... OUTPUT_VARIABLE _Version)`

In the second version, the standard output and standard inputs of the commands chain together.

If you want to do anything more complex, you'll have to create a separate script and invoke it in a process-, not shell-, oriented way, i.e. option 1.