# CMake Parse error Function missing ending ")". Instead found unterminated string with text ")

Tags: c++, cmake

First of all I wanna say I am aware of below questions

[Parse error. Function missing ending ")" CMAKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44725059/parse-error-function-missing-ending-cmake?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[CMake's execute_process and arbitrary shell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689501/cmakes-execute-process-and-arbitrary-shell-scripts)

But I couldn't understand solution provided in these questions, because I don't know much about cmake commands and also I think my problem context is different.

I am trying to compile https://github.com/openalpr/imageclipper this software.
I am following instructions in README file which says to do only two following commands

1.) cmake ./

2.) make

But while issuing first command I get this error ->

---

C:\Users\vishal tewatia\Downloads\imageclipper-master>cmake ./
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:25:
  Parse error.  Function missing ending ")".  Instead found unterminated
  string with text ")

ENDIF()

SET(SRC

src/imageclipper.cpp

)

ADD_EXECUTABLE( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC} )

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS}

C:/boost_1_65_1/stage/lib

)".

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/vishal tewatia/Downloads/imageclipper-master/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

---

Below is CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6) 

project(imageclipper)
SET(PROJECT_VERSION "0.1")


SET(OpenCV_DIR "C:\opencv\build\install\x64\vc15\bin\")


# Opencv Package
FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED )
IF (${OpenCV_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 2.3.0)
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "OpenCV version is not compatible : 
${OpenCV_VERSION}")
ENDIF()



SET(SRC
  src/imageclipper.cpp
)

ADD_EXECUTABLE( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC} )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( ${PROJECT_NAME}  ${OpenCV_LIBS} 
    C:/boost_1_65_1/stage/lib
    )
```

I don't understand why is it says that function has missing ")" , because in CMakeLists.txt file all opened brackets are closed.
or if the error is regarding "C:/boost_1_65_1/stage/lib" this address not properly formatted , I am not sure then what to do , Please help.

Comment: Perhaps a problem with backward slashes in the path when you set `OpenCV_DIR`? Backward slashes in CMake strings needs to be escaped like in C++ strings.

Comment: That's likely it. Best to just use forward slashes all the time.

Comment: and set custom paths on the command line, not in cmake code. Otherwise when I try to build your project on a machine where I have installed opencv somewhere else, it won't work!

Answer (score 4):

ok , so I found the solution , All it needs is \\ instead of \ while setting OpenCV_DIR